# ¿Cómo puedo listar valores en 0 y superiores 1, ambos inclusive en MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Requiero listar un reporte con código, compañía, nombre de contacto, teléfono y cantidad de órdenes que ha realizado cada cliente. Este debe mostrar todos los clientes, que hayan realizado órdenes o no.

Base de datos Northwind, tabla customers y orders en MySql

Tengo armada la siguiente sintaxis pero no me funciona, **no arroja ninguna información al ejecutar**, necesito de su apoyo por favor en función de ver si tengo un error que no logro visualizar.

```sql
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID,
    CompanyName,
    ContactName,
    Phone,
    Count(orderID)
FROM 
    customers 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, Phone
ORDER BY 5;
```

El resultado esperado sería este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Por qué haces left outer join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay errores variados. Primero usas mal los alias(c y o) de las tablas, y está mal el agrupado con el conteo.
Esto sería lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT 
    c.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    c.ContactName,
    c.Phone,
    count(o.CustomerID)as 'ordenes realizadas'
FROM 
    customers c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
ORDER BY c.CompanyName;
```

El agrupado funciona así: con esto `GROUP BY c.CustomerID` le estás diciendo que agrupe por cliente y si además lo usas en combinación con la función count() `count(o.CustomerID)` lo que hace es **agrupar** por cliente el **conteo** de las veces que aparece cada cliente en la tabla **orders**.
Después el `ORDER BY c.CompanyName` devuelve los registros ordenados por el/los campo indicado, si son nombres como en este caso los ordena alfabéticamente en orden ascendente, y si le agregas `desc`, en orden descendente

Comment: si, perdón, me olvidé las comillas simples, ya lo edito, pero no comparto que mi agrupamiento este mal, si a mi me funciona, además lo más lógico es agrupar por un solo campo (campo clave), ya que se necesita contar las ordenes que tiene cada cliente, o sea de la tabla `orders` se cuenta cuántas veces aparece ese `CustomerID`. Me gustaría que me digas por qué está mal, o sea en que caso me va a fallar haciéndolo de esa forma